# Find patterns in a string in Python and printing

Tags: python, parsing, awk

So I have the following string variable in python: pytest_summary

And its content is: "1 failed, 316 passed, 204 warnings, 0 skipped, 0 xfailed in 40.82s"

I need a way to look for specific patterns inside the strings such as "passed", and then save the number in front of it (i.e 316) to a variable. I used to do this using awk or sed which is much easier and faster, but I have no idea how to do this in python.

My ultimate goal is to have a code that is able to find any pattern I ask inside of the string (i.e look fir passed, warnings, etc) And save the number in front of the pattern to a variable, to later be added to a dictionary.

Comment: like str.find()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this. For example, you can use regular expressions like this:

```
from re import findall

pytest_summary = "1 failed, 316 passed, 204 warnings, 0 skipped, 0 xfailed in 40.82s"
result = findall('([0-9]+) ([a-z]+)', pytest_summary)
print (result)
# --> [('1', 'failed'), ('316', 'passed'), ('204', 'warnings'), ('0', 'skipped'), ('0', 'xfailed')]
```

So now you have the parts collected in a list.
To convert that to a dictionary, and at the same time convert the numerical strings to integers:

```
result = {key: int(value) for value, key in result}
print (result)
# --> {'failed': 1, 'passed': 316, 'warnings': 204, 'skipped': 0, 'xfailed': 0}
```

Of course, if you want, you can do the whole thing in a single line:

```
result = {key: int(value) for value, key in findall('([0-9]+) ([a-z]+)', pytest_summary)}
```

It might be advisable to wrap that code inside `try: ... except ValueError:`, just in case the input string happens to contain something that isn’t a valid integer number.

Answer (score 0):

```py
s = '1 failed, 316 passed, 204 warnings, 0 skipped, 0 xfailed in 40.82s'
parts = [v.strip().split() for v in s.replace(' in ', ',').split(',')]

d = {p[1]: int(p[0]) for p in parts[:-1]}
duration = ' '.join(parts[-1])
```

That gives you:

```py
>>> d
{'failed': 1, 'passed': 316, 'warnings': 204, 'skipped': 0, 'xfailed': 0}

>>> duration
'40.82s'
```

From there, you can handle as you like...